Why Azure DevOps "Tests" timings are so different across screens?
I am trying to figure out which timing of the test runs is correct since there are 3 different timings I can see. Can someone please suggest which one is the correct timing for the tests run? And also why they are all different?
Timing shown under "Summary" tab for the pipeline run

Timing shown under "Tests" tab on the pipeline run

Timings shown under "test-results-trend" widget (showing on my DevOps dashboard)

I was expecting them to match and show same timings on all screens.
03-06-2024 EDIT
Please see another run of parallel tests and timings are quite different between widget and the Tests tab.


05-06-2024 - EDIT
Thanks. I am adding more details for individual tests step names and you can see that there is still no clear corelation between the total time shown on widget. How can we say that 16m31s is matching with 16m52s?



Timing shown under "Summary" tab for the pipeline run:
This is the whole pipeline run execution time, not only test run execution.
Timing shown under "Tests" tab on the pipeline run:
This is the effective run duration for all tests. You can find duration for each test on the bottom.

Timings shown under "test-results-trend" widget (showing on my DevOps dashboard)
It appears you are not checking on the same build. The duration on the widget should be identical with above one on Tests tab.  You can click on the widget column and it will redirect to the pipeline, you can confirm if duration is same.

In above, the duration on Tests and widget are the correct timing for test run. The time on Tests is more accurate as it has ms for the time.
Hope it's helps.
Edit:
The widget is tracking the test duration based on the test run title, it could also happen that you have more than one test run in your pipeline, in this cases, you can expand the test details on Tests tab, check the target test run duration, it should be same with the widget.

Add more:
Since the widget is tracking the test duration based on the test run title, if your tests are run on parallel agents, the duration on widget will add all time together for same test run between different agents.


In my specific case, tests are run on parallel agents. Also there are more than 1 running same time hence there is more to add to the confusion. I am not sure how the widget is calculating the time since its surely different between the tests tab and the widget. Please see additional details added. Surely the test run is same.

@ankurkapoor, i edited the answer with add more content for tests on parallel agents. Please have a check. if you still have any queries, please show the tests run name  details on Tests tab, and widget configuration. Thanks.

Thanks. Please see more details on the above with new screenshots.

@ankurkapoor, can you show the widget configuration? Which test run title is it tracking? Also please confirm you are checking on same build as the name is redacted.
